# Write data from one file to another line by line

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, text-files

I have two text files which appear as such:

names.txt:

```
andrew
brian
ben
jerry
katie
katherine
```

and nums.txt

```
123
456
789
012
345
678
```

My code currently looks like this, which adds one file to the end of the other.

```
with open("nums.txt",) as f:
    with open("names.txt", "a") as f1:
        for line in f:
            f1.write(line)
```

What I want to happen is to add line 1 from the second file, to the end of line 1 on the first file, so that the output file will be:

```
andrew123
brian456

etc.
```

Comment: Do you really have to do it in Python ? Under UNIX, "paste file1 file2" will do what you expect.

Comment: You will have to create a separate output file containing the combined data — or write the results to a temporary file and replace one of input files with it afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
t1=open('names.txt').read().split()
t2=open('nums.txt').read().split()
t=[i+k+'\n' for i, k in zip(t1,t2)]
with open('new.txt', 'w') as f:
    for i in t:
        f.write(i)
```

Output:

```
andrew123
brian456
ben789
jerry012
katie345
katherine678
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain this? It worked but as I'm still young in my Python learning, can you explain it in detail please?

Comment: Sure. The code reads the 2 files and creates one list per file where each element represents a seperate line. Then it creates a 3rd list where each element is the concatenation of the elements of the 2 lists at the same position (1st with 1st, 2nd with 2nd, etc).
Finally it writes a new txt file, where every line is an element of this 3rd list

Answer (score 1):

You can open the two files, iterate line by line in both, and output to another file.

```
with open("names.txt") as f1, open("nums.txt") as f2, open("out.txt","w") as f_out: 
    for name, num in zip(f1, f2):
        f_out.write(f"{name.strip()}{num.strip()}\n")
```